# SQL Server: calculate employee commission

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `employee` with few columns as:

```
empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,commission,deptno
```

So I want to display name and commission together with another column that shows their commission increased by 10%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,commission,commission*1.1 AS commission_10p, deptno
```

Comment: An increase of 20% would be commission * 1.2  = 1 * commission + (20/100) * commission = 1 * commission + (2/10) * commission

Comment: please explain the formula of taking the percentage? i can't understand what you said???.

Comment: Example: You have a commission of 100,-. A 20% increase would mean 20,- and with this the increased commission would be 120,- - do you agree so far? However 20% is the same as 20/100 is the same as 2/10 is the same as 0.2 - so the increased commission is the same as 1 (equals 100%) * commission + 0.2 (equals the 20%) * commission

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement simply a 10% increase in the commission column you may use the below SQL which i tried on my local system.

**--Table Creation**

```
create table employee(
empno int,
ename varchar(100),
job varchar(100),
mgr varchar(100),
hiredate datetime,
sal int,
commission int,
deptno int)
```

**--Dummy Value Insert**

```
insert into employee
values
(001,'John Doe','Dev','Bruce Wayne',getdate(),4500,100,101),
(002,'Donald Duck','Test','Superman',getdate(),6500,80,102),
(003,'Mickey Mouse','IT','Batman',getdate(),7000,70,103)
```

[image]

**--increase commission by 10%**

```
select 
    ename,
    commission,
    increased_commission = (commission*1.1) 
from employee
```

[image]

Comment: Guess there is a mistake: increased_commission = (commission*0.1) should be increased_commission = commission + (commission*0.1)

Comment: thanks, i had only displayed the increased commission value.